# Product of two functions with compactly supported Fourier transforms

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory, functional-calculus

**Question 1:** Suppose $a,b\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R})\cap L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$. Is it possible that the pointwise product $ab$ equals the constant function $1$ and both $a$ and $b$ have compactly supported Fourier transforms?

I would like to understand a specific example (if it exists) but don't know enough of the theory to find one.

**Question 2:** A more specific problem that I have in mind is whether there exist functions $a$ and $b$ defined on $\mathbb{R}\backslash U$, where $U$ is a small open neighbourhood around $0$, such that:

- $a,b$ are odd functions,
- $a\rightarrow\pm 1$ at $\pm\infty$,
- $ab=1$ on $\mathbb{R}\backslash U$,
- both $a$ and $b$ have compactly supported Fourier transforms.

**Remark:** To provide some context for the question, my motivation for considering whether such $a$ and $b$ exist comes from trying to do functional calculus of a self-adjoint elliptic differential operator $D$, for example $D=-i\frac{d}{dx}$ on $\mathbb{R}$. The compactness of the supports of $\hat{a}$ and $\hat{b}$ have to do with $a(D)$ and $b(D)$ having "finite propagation".

Comment: $a=b=1{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Is there a similarly simple example for the second question? I guess one difference there is that the simplest odd function, namely the sign function, does not have compactly supported Fourier transform.

Comment: Let $\hat{\phi} $ be an even $C^\infty_c$ approximation of $1_{[-N,N]}$ and set $\hat{a} = \hat{\phi} \ pv(\frac{-1}{\pi \xi})$ ($pv$ for principal value) then $a$ will be a $C^\infty$ and odd approximation of $sign(x)$ : $a(x) = sign \ast \phi(x)$ with $\phi$ smooth fast decreasing and $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(x)dx=1$ so $a(\pm\infty ) =\pm 1$

Comment: Is it clear that $b$ has compactly supported Fourier transform in that example?

Comment: If $\hat{a},\hat{b}$ are compactly supported distributions then their convolution is a well-defined compactly supported distribution 

so $ab = \mathcal{F}^{-1}[\hat{a} \ast \hat{b}]$ is analytic and $ab(x) = 1$ for $x > r$ implies $ab(x) = 1$ for every $x$. Then $a,b$ continuous odd implies $ab(0) = 0$ a contradiction.

Comment: With $a(D)$ you mean the operator $a(D)( f)(x) := \mathcal{F}^{-1}[a(2\pi \xi) \hat{f}(\xi)](x)= \mathcal{F}^{-1}[a(2\pi .)] \ast f(x)$

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If $a$ and $b$ are odd then certainly $ab(0)=0$, which already contradicts $ab=1$. But if $a$ and $b$ are only defined on $\mathbb{R}\backslash U$ (and only odd there), is there still a contradiction?

Comment: The compactly supported FT implies $ab$ is analytic so when asking $ab(x) = 1$ for $x > r$ you get $ab(x) = 1$ for every $x$. If you relax it to $ab(x) \approx 1$ then see my 2nd comment.

Comment: What I'm wondering is whether the following two facts are contradictory: 1. $ab(x)=1$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ (which you established by analyticity), and 2. $a$ and $b$ are odd outside of the small open neighbourhood $U$ of $0$?